# Cannot get QR4Office to link to a sharepoint Excel file cell using smart phone to read

Tags: office-addins

I am able to use the "Link to this range" function to get an Excel cell link to create a QR code, however when I try  to use a tablet or smartphone to locate the cell linked I get the right document but a "couldn't navigate" ribbon each time. Is there a way to get this to work?

see above for full description